# Sorting Accounts

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-account

I have some accounts on android device that stored in accounts table in contacts2.db;
How can i sort them by asc?

I have not found access to accounts table from ContactsContract.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean `Contacts` or `Accounts`?

Comment: Accounts that can be added by AccountManager or Accounts&Sync from Settings activity

Answer (score 0):

To get list of accounts you have to use `AccountManager`, not Contacts' content provider. Do this.

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
   ...
}
```

And sort it as you want. Also note app have to request GET_ACCOUNTS permission to do that:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: You cant swap items from Account[] accounts.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to rearange array?

Comment: Some accounts cannot be removed for rearrange

Comment: What elaborating?Sorry i dont understand your last comment

Comment: "Some accounts cannot be removed for rearrange". You got just array. I see no reason for not being able o do with it what I want

Comment: If you look at github/android u will see that its array from database table.